# how do i detect input[type="file"] name in server side (<input type="file">)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image

I have written a php script for uploading images. I want to use this script in my all pages. The problem is that the name of input file `<input type="file" name="input_name">` in the server side. I am using a different input name so I do not know how I detect the input name in the server side?

Html code :

```
<input type="file" name="my_input_name" id="inptId">
```

JS Code:

```
  var fd = new FormData();
  var image = document.getElementById("inptId");
  fd.append("my_input_name",image);
  $.ajax({
   method:post,
   url:uniq_file_uploader.php,
   ....,
   ....,
   data:fd,
   sucess:function(e){....}
  });
```

EG: my php code:

```
<?php
 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "post"){
  if(!empty($_FILES['Constant_Name']['name'][0])){//check also for multiple uploads
     // constant_name is name of input file (eg. my_input_name)
    // but problem is input name is not always same..
   // on every page it is different name

  }else {return "NO file selected";}
  if(!empty($_FILES['Constant_Name']['name'])){
    //it is for one file upload detect
    //this is for one file upload beacuse this is for using upload his avatar. can't be a lot of avatar
  }else{return "no file selected";}
 }else {return "request is not post"}
?>
```

Comment: Why are your severside and clientside not matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "post"){
  if(!empty($_FILES)) {
     $cname = key($_FILES); //get the first key from $_FILES
  } else {
     $cname = '';
  }
  if(!empty($_FILES[$cname]['name'][0])){//check also for multiple uploads
     // constant_name is name of input file (eg. my_input_name)
    // but problem is input name is not always same..
   // on every page it is different name

  }else {return "NO file selected";}
  if(!empty($_FILES[$cname]['name'])){
    //it is for one file upload detect

  }else{return "no file selected";}
 }else {return "request is not post"}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe someone do not understand simple key function. If it works for you just add up vote

Comment: Thankss a lot i searched  a lot  on google but i could find any solution.. thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You can access it with `$_FILES['my_input_name']` just like `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

Comment: u do not understand question... I ask how do i detect input name  in server side ?